# Desk stain still tacky in a few places after a week and a half

Tags: stain, oil

I have been reading all of these looking for an answer.  I stained my desk with two coats, oil base, then we had humidity.  I have yet to do a clear coat.  Most of this desk has dried yet still some spots on the top where I want to place a glass top over it. Someone suggested a Quick Dry Spray.  I know nothing about that.  Is it a possibility?  I have a deadline before this desk has to go into a working office.  Is there such a thing as a Quick Dry Spray ?

Comment: More about the stain please? Brand, age, storage conditions?

Comment: Did you wipe/rub off excess stain directly after application (most oil stains recommend this...)?

Comment: Yes I did. But seriously right after i did the second coat we had fog roll that evening, followed by several days, four/five, of very high humidity. Yesterday and today the humidity was low. Right now I've moved it carefully into the sun. There are reasons why it has taken time to dry and I understand the weather, but a week and a half is too long for me. Options?

Comment: Sorry, just saw this. I used Minwax stain. New cans, two different colors. First coat was too light. I bought them the week before I started this project. The work done in my garage.

Comment: And is there such a thing as a Quick Dry Coat that would work?

Comment: Use the comments to reply to other commenters not the answer space

Comment: Maggie, you have added 3 answers which are not answers but clarifications to your question. We are a Q&A site, not a discussion forum, and we work differently.  Here you use the [edit] button to add detail to your question.  It's right below the keywords.   Using answers as discussion threads won't work, least because their order is randomized. If you have learned the discussion forum trick of posting replies to "bump" a thread to the top of the list, know that **[edit]ing a question has the same effect**.

Comment: I should have asked but it would be good to have the exact product/color identification, on the off chance the two are incompatible.

Comment: What finish was on it before and how did you strip it?  Does the new stained finish look even?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there such a thing as a Quick Dry Spray?

Not that I've heard of for this application. I recommend using a clean cloth with mineral spirits (paint thinner) to uniformly wipe down the entire surface, this will remove standing stain that has not been able to penetrate the wood fibers.

For what it's worth, I think your problem may have less to do with humidity and more to do with inability of the second coat of stain to penetrate and soak into the wood fibers completely in all areas...

Comment: And there are lots of reasons for incomplete penetration, including dense wood fibers (knots), surface contamination (old finish, wax, grease, dirt, etc.), over-application...